# Is it possible to create a microsite to search record in data extension and edit the record?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, microsites

Is it possible to create a smart capture form in a microsite and add search functionality to search record in data extension and edit the record from the microsite?

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that a smart capture form would give you the full flexibility to accomplish what you are looking for.

What I would recommend is:

1. Create a webform for your search field
2. Write AMPScript to retrieve the record from the DE ([LookupRows](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/#LookupRows) or [Lookup](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/) would likely be your best places)
3. Create a webform for your editing of the result
4. Write AMPScript to recieve and upsert this info into your DE. ([UpsertData](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/upsertdata/#UpsertData))
5. Place each of these into a single LP and have the webforms post to themselves.

You would need to include logic (such as a hidden field on each form) to allow the page to differentiate which AMPScript and Webform to show (via AMPScript IF THEN statement).  This would allow you the simplest way (by using a landing page) to edit a single record outside of using the tools available inside SFMC.

If you need multiple records edited, I would look into using something like the [FuelUX repeater](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#repeater) along with API calls to retrieve and update your data.

If you don't need it hosted on a SFMC landing page, I would look into using the SOAP or REST API, which would likely be much more efficient and effective.

Comment: Thank you for your response. A few questions: (1) By webform, do you mean a HTML form in a microsite?, (2) If I use input box for search team and use LookupRows, how the search results can be displayed on a microsite page?, (3) What do you mean by LP?